# Can't import gadu gadu contact list from server

Tags: 11.10, empathy

I can't import gadu gadu contact list from server. I am using empathy 3.2.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome shell.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install telepathy-sunshine`.

Restart empathy and then go to preferences of your GG and check export contacts.